# Can we update the duplicate post finder to include other users?

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions

This question originated from [this MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316539/993547) where there is a discussion on an exact duplicate question by another user.

The case itself is curious enough, and [Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao) asked a good question in a comment:

> Afaik, there is some automated process behind word to word copied answers ... Aint there anything like that for questions?

The comment on that from [Brad Larson ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson):

> Even for answers, that only detects duplicate answers by the same person, not by different people.

So it seems you are more likely to be flagged for copying your own content, than that of another user! It seems the community has to find those duplicates though SEDE or just luck.

I propose to extend the auto-flag script, to include questions and *exact* copies of other users too. I know this might be very expensive to do, and that might be the reason to reject this, but I hope there is a possibility to build this (and maybe run this just once a day/week if that is the best possible).

Comment: I know this has been brought up in the past, but can't remember if any of it was public. Moderators have talked about this with SE employees in regards to plagiarism detection, and the general indication was that there would be serious performance consequences that might not scale to a site like SO. They'd have to comment on that, though.

Comment: It may not scale to SO, but it could on other sites. The check could be restricted to other answers *on the same question* and still be useful; or (less useful) to other answers on the same question where the answer is subject to a review queue listing.